# package does not exist mvn clean install

Tags: java, maven, compiler-errors, pom.xml

I'm working on a multi module maven project with this structure :

ats-parent has 3 children : ats-api, ats-client, ats-impl

ats-impl has 4 children: ats-accountManager, ats-common, ats-noticeManager, ats-applicationContext.

moreover ats-common depends on ats-api.

So here is my problem :

when I try to run mvn clean install i have the error :

```
/home/frozen/workspace/ATS/ats-parent/ats-impl/ats-common/src/main/java/com/o2xp/ats/common/services/ti/CategoryService.java:[5,31] package com.o2xp.ats.api.common does not exist
```

I precise that CategoryService which is ats common uses some classes into ats-api. Moreover i checked the detailed log and i refers to the lines corresponding to the imports of classes from the api module

Here is the pom of ats-common :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <artifactId>ats-impl</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.o2xp</groupId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <artifactId>ats-common</artifactId>
  <name>ats-common</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.o2xp</groupId>
        <artifactId>ats-api</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

the pom of ats-api :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <start-class>com.o2xp.ats.accountManager.App</start-class>    
  </properties>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.o2xp</groupId>
    <artifactId>ats-parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <groupId>com.o2xp</groupId>
  <artifactId>ats-api</artifactId>
  <name>ats-api</name>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

and the pom of ats-impl :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>    
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <groupId>com.o2xp</groupId>
  <artifactId>ats-impl</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>ats-impl</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.196</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
        <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.jhipster</groupId>
        <artifactId>jhipster</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <modules>
    <module>ats-application-context</module>
    <module>ats-notice-manager</module>
    <module>ats-common</module>
    <module>ats-accountManager</module>
  </modules>
</project>
```

the other modules are compiled except ats-accountManager which is skipped because it is after ats-common.

Comment: In the ats-parent pom what is the order of the modules? Is the ats-api before the ats-imp?

Comment: no it is after should i change it ?

Comment: I think you should. Maven builds the modules in order they appear in the `<modules>` list, so if you have a dependency on the api module then it should be built first.

Comment: it didn't worked i still have a failure on compiling ats-common module.

Comment: @BalázsNemes i found something weird it is only one package (com.o2xp.ats.api.comon) of ats-api which is not found if it can help you

Comment: If the dependencies given correctly the order is automatically done by Maven...there is something else wrong...

Answer (score 0):

package `com.o2xp.ats.api.common` belongs to your api module.

Change

```
 <modules>
 <module>ats-application-context</module>
 <module>ats-notice-manager</module>
 <module>ats-common</module>
 <module>ats-accountManager</module>
</modules>
```

to

```
 <modules>
    <module>ats-application-context</module>
    <module>ats-notice-manager</module>
    <module>ats-accountManager</module>
  </modules>
```

`ats-common` module will be build by `ats-api` module

Comment: the package in CategoryService.java is : package com.o2xp.ats.common.services.ti not com.o2xp.ats.api.common

Comment: search by your code , somewhere you have package `com.o2xp.ats.api.common`

Comment: i searched in all classes from the common module and all their classes are starting by :  package com.o2xp.ats.common

Comment: but see the exception `package com.o2xp.ats.API.common does not exist`

Comment: the exception means that you have somewhere in your code `api` in a package name. Double check it.

Comment: i did but i think it's the import of some classes which belongs to the api module which can't be resolved. Moreover if i had used a wrong name of package, eclipse should telle me there is an error.

Comment: ats-api is already a child of ats-parent and ats-common is a child of ats-impl which is himself a son of ats-parent like ats-api so i have to let this line : <module>ats-common</module> in the ats-impl pom you want me to show you the pom of my ats-parent ?

Comment: maybe should i specify a version of maven builder ?

Comment: try to delete `<module>ats-common</module>` from modules in the pom

Comment: sure it works but ats-common isn't built like if it doesn't exist in my project

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in my ats-parent pom i had added spring boot as a parent i just removed this and it's working